# Analytic function in open unit disc.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove that there exist an analytic function $f$ of $|z|<1$ onto itself such that $f(0)=1/2$, $f(1/2)=1/3$  and  $f(1/3)=1/4$.

Comment: I think we can use Schwarz lemma but how to use it.

Comment: $f\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{4}$ suggests that $f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=\frac{1}{z+1}$ i.e., $f\left(z\right)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ would be one choice but then $f(0)\neq \frac{1}{2}$ in that case... Try something like that

Comment: but its not the exact way.

Comment: It does not work always to use full hypothesis to construct function.. We use some partial hypothesis and then construct some function and see if remaining hypothesis is satisfied by that function that we have constructed... Are you saying $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ is not analytic? Are you saying that Image of $f$ is out side unit disc?? Yes of course it is hit and try...

Comment: Actually it Schwarz lemma application problem so we should use that only thats why i am saying....it is better we we use that exact way.

Comment: your solution is ok but we can not solve all problems by force ..

Comment: I agree that you can not use this idea to do other problems.... But schwarz lemma does not say about existence of some function it only says if you have some holomorphic function $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(0)=0$ then $|f(z)|\leq z$.. So, i am not very sure how do you use this to prove existence... If you are following some book then let me know what book it is so that  i can see if some thing can be done...

Comment: S.Ponnusamy  page number 261 problem number 6.75(j)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of the Pick-Nevanlinna interpolation problem. The existence of the function is equivalent to a positive semi-definiteness of a simple 3 by 3 matrix: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevanlinna%E2%80%93Pick_interpolation

Comment: n point generalization of the Schwarz lemma

Comment: Yes, the lemma is mentioned in the article...

Comment: ok sir thanks now i can handle the problem.....thanks for good affords..

Comment: how to prove that there exist an analytic function on the unit disc onto itself such that f(3/4)=3/4 and derivative at 2/3 is equal to 3/4

Comment: please try to solve it..

Comment: Well, the second condition can be written as $f(2/3+\epsilon)-f(2/3)\approx\epsilon*3/4$...

Comment: ok please explane..

Comment: are you using definition of derivative..

Comment: Yes, trying to reduce the problem to the previous one...

Comment: but how the existence of such a function?

Comment: Is there information about $f(2/3)$ or only about the derivative?

Comment: the question is does there exist an analytic function on the unit disc to itself with f(3/4)=3/4 and its derivative at 2/3 is equal to 3/4

Comment: and answer is yes there exist such a function

Comment: again i am trying using Schwartz lemma..

Comment: Trying looking at $g(z)=\tau\circ f\circ\tau(z)$, where $\tau(z)=\frac{3/4-z}{1-3/4*z}$ and applying chain rule and the Schwarz lemma ..

Comment: how you construct it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is of the form: $f(z)=\tau\circ(z\frac{a-z}{1-\bar{a}z})\circ\tau(z)$. This implies $f(3/4)=3/4$. Now, we need to solve for $a$ for the second condition w/the chain rule...

Comment: ok sir now i try to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

We could try transporting the problem to another domain that is easier to handle than the unit disk - I will use the standard map to the Poincaré half-plane $H = \{ z \in \mathbb C,\; \mathrm{Im} z > 0\}$ given by $h(w) =i\frac{1+w}{1-w}$. Your problem then becomes: to find a map $g: H \rightarrow H$ such that $g(i) = 3i$, $g(3i) = 2i$, $g(2i) = 5i/3$; or, to find a map $g: \mathbb C \rightarrow \mathbb C$ satisfying the same conditions plus $g(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$.

Now, the condition $g(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$ means that $g$ is a real-analytic map. Given that we have a finite number of points to interpolate, we will even decide that $g$ is a polynomial. To fix the imaginary axis, we will use a odd polynomial. The smallest odd polynomial interpolating the values we want is
$$ g(x) = (31x^5+415x^3+1464x)/360 \qquad \tiny\textrm{(bleuargh)}.$$
A solution to your original problem is therefore
$$ f = h^-1 \circ g \circ h, w \mapsto \frac{-360 w^5
 + 1613 w^4
 - 1917 w^3
 - 117 w^2
 + 713 w
 - 180}{-180 w^5
 + 713 w^4
 - 117 w^3
 - 1917 w^2
 + 1613 w
 - 360}.$$

*EDIT:*
(In the Poincaré half-plane, real polynomials are fine. In the unit disk, we could have proceeded directly in the same way with Fourier series.)

Comment: ok i try to solve it..